# anyone know if you can reset the visualsvn trial?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

I must have installed it at some point in the past, but never really used it. I'd like to actually give it a try now but it's saying the trial has expired (which is why i'm assuming i must have installed it at some point in the past).

Anyone know if there's a way to get another 30 days to test it out?

Comment: Buy it or ask them.  We're not going to help you break their trialware protection.

Comment: I wasn't trying to cheat or break any trialware stuff. I honestly just needed to try it again since i had installed it some time in the past and never got around to using it. FYI you can email their support and they'll send you a license key which is good for another 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to contact sales@visualsvn.com and ask them for another evaluation license. They will be happy to provide one.

Another way is remove license key from registry and reinstall VisualSVN, but for me it's little bit hacky.

Comment: i'm not sure where in the registry the license key is - so i'll try contacting sales. thanks

Comment: Where would be the licence key for the Visual Svn Thanks